# python: IndexError by deleating an element of the list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I want to program a function that solves a mathematic task. The task is given to the function as list (e.g. [3, '+', 4, '*', 15]) and should be solved by regarding that multiplication and division have to be prefered.

```
def getresult(TaskAsList):
    """Ermitle Ergebnis einer Aufgabe – Aufgabe muss als Liste zugeführt werden"""
    while len(TaskAsList)>1:
        for i in range(len(TaskAsList)-1):
                if TaskAsList[i] == '*':
                    TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]*TaskAsList[i+1]
                    del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                    del(TaskAsList[i])
                elif TaskAsList[i] == ':':
                    TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]/TaskAsList[i+1]
                    print(i)
                    del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                    del(TaskAsList[i])
        for i in range(len(TaskAsList)-1):
                if TaskAsList[i] == '+':
                    TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]+TaskAsList[i+1]
                    del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                    del(TaskAsList[i])
                elif TaskAsList[i] == '-':
                    TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]-TaskAsList[i+1]
                    del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                    del(TaskAsList[i])

    return TaskAsList[0]
```

By trying this, an IndexError will be raised.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
 <module>   File "./task_generator.py", line 30, in getresult
     del(TaskAsList[i]) IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you really want `:` to be the division operator?

Comment: Iteration + modifying the size of the container is something you do *not* want.

Comment: Works for me.  63 is that what you want?

Comment: @user2357112 that is only the displayed operator

Comment: @Jim: Yes, which version of python did you use?

Comment: 2.7.3 is the version.

Answer (score 1):

After you set the range to iterate over, you delete elements from the list, changing its size. The program attempts to iterate over as many items as there were from the start, but there aren't that many items any more.

(`del` isn't a function. Don't put parentheses around the target.)

Answer (score 0):

because you initialize a range running to the first initial length of your list. But if you delete some indexes you list gets smaller... and the for runs still to the initial length

By the way... is your list consisting of double elements? otherwise you might get trouble with your accuracy at the devision

Comment: Thankyou, there are only elements of the types Integer and String in the list.

Comment: If you divide 7 by 3 you will get 2, if you devide with integers. It would be better, if you go through the values and declare them to be double, where a double devision would give you 2.33333[...] ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getresult(TaskAsList):
    while len(TaskAsList)>1:
        while ('*' in TaskAsList) or (':' in TaskAsList):
            for i in range(len(TaskAsList)-1):
                    if TaskAsList[i] == '*':
                        TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]*TaskAsList[i+1]
                        del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                        del(TaskAsList[i])
                        break
                    elif TaskAsList[i] == ':':
                        TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]/TaskAsList[i+1]
                        print(i)
                        del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                        del(TaskAsList[i])
                        break
        for i in range(len(TaskAsList)-1):
                if TaskAsList[i] == '+':
                    TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]+TaskAsList[i+1]
                    del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                    del(TaskAsList[i])
                    break
                elif TaskAsList[i] == '-':
                    TaskAsList[i-1] = TaskAsList[i-1]-TaskAsList[i+1]
                    del(TaskAsList[i+1])
                    del(TaskAsList[i])
                    break

    return TaskAsList[0]
```

Comment: Sorry but this still raises an IndexError

Comment: It won't work if you have an operator at the end?  Are you doing RPN?